# paypal php rest api. response codes?

Tags: php, rest, paypal

This whole paypal process has been one nightmare after the next. I've managed to complete the application all except for one small problem. the response object from paypal `Payment::execute()` has no documentation. My front end is client side, so i really have no way of knowing what this response array contains.

here's what i've got so far:

```
    $paymentId = $this->ppconf; //stores paymentId

    if(empty($paymentId)){Throw New \Exception('missing payment id'); }

    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($z);
    $response = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext); // i need to know what this response array looks like and what the response codes are, so i can generate my $result array for my application.

    $state = $response->getState();
    $failures = ['failed','canceled','expired'];
    if(in_array($state,$failures)){
        $result = ['type'=>'error'];
    }else{
        $result = ['type'=>'success'];
        $this->finished = true;
    }

    return $result;
```

Comment: There is some documentation for the status codes available on https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#errors

Comment: thanks but, it still doesn't tell me what the output of `Payment::execute()` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

> Returns a payment object for the completed PayPal payment.

So presumably an instance of an [PayPal\Api\Payment Object](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php).

You should be able to grab the state property of the payment using the following:

```
$response->getState();
```

Returning one of the following strings:

> created, approved, failed, canceled, expired